# How to output a char array with while and putchar

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I have a for loop to output an array but would like to rewrite it with a while loop.

I have the following for loop that works fine:

```
 for (i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
        putchar(output[i]);
```

and I have tried to rewrite the code above in a while loop:

```
while (i < arrayLength){

        putchar(output[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

The problem is that when I run the code with the while loop,  I get no output but the program ends

when I run it with a for loop, I get the expected output of

`defghi`

What have I done wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the declaration of `i`, do you initialize it with 0?

Comment: Have you initialized `i`? If not there will be a random value in it which easily can be greater than `arrayLength`. In that case the loop will never be entered. Probably a good moment to learn a bit about Debuggers and how to step through your code line by line.

Comment: yes I have, right at the beginning I initialise it as `i=0`

Comment: so you are keeping off some code, this makes it tough for others to help you:(https://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankieBoyle do you flush the output witting a `\n` after the _while_ ? (answer edited)

Comment: I get the feeling that you are just reusing `i` from your for loop in your while loop do you? Because if so `i` will already be equal to `arrayLength` and thus the while loop will never be entered

Comment: @Yastanub then there will be the output of `putchar()` in the for-loop. with no mcve, we can only speculate

Answer (score 0):

in

```
for (i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++)
        putchar(output[i]);
```

i is initialized by the *for*, but in

```
while (i < arrayLength){

        putchar(output[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

*i* is not initialized before the while, probably its value is `> arrayLength` so the *while* never executes its body, just add `i = 0;` before the *while*

---

**(edit)**

You say you initialize *i* with 0 somewhere before, do you flush the output writing a `\n` after the *while* ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons why does something like that happens, more over because you explained in your comment:

```
yes I have, right at the beginning I initialise it as i=0
```

Please check this code and tell us what are the differences between this one and your actual code (which by the way you do not show it us):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char output[] = "ABCDEFG";
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    size_t arrayLength = strlen( output );

    for ( i = 0 ; i < arrayLength ; i++ )
    {
        putchar(output[i]);
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    j = 0;
    while ( j < arrayLength )
    {

        putchar( output[j] );
        j++;
    }
}
```

You should provide a code which we can test it.

Are you running both LOOPs in the same code?
Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char output[] = "ABCDEFG";
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t arrayLength = strlen( output );

    for ( i = 0 ; i < arrayLength ; i++ )
    {
        putchar(output[i]);
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    while ( i < arrayLength )
    {

        putchar( output[i] );
        i++;
    }
}
```

?